# File not found in jar

Tags: java, file, jar, embedded-resource

I'm working in java swing application. I'm using icon images which is placed inside **uploads** folder. When i run my project it's working fine.

I export my project as jar. When i run my jar file it show **file not found** error.

This is my code,

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(Config.IMAGE_RESOURCE_FOLDER + "/" + fileName));
```

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S0XW.png)

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: BTW - what is the value of `Config.IMAGE_RESOURCE_FOLDER` (what path does it point to)?

Comment: Config.IMAGE_RESOURCE_FOLDER = "images"

Comment: I'm using this functionality inside static method. So when i use 
    this.getClass().getResource("/path/to/the.resource"); it's not working. Instead of this i tried with sttic method class also. But not working.

Comment: Your code is currently looking for a file located in the directory `./images`, where `.` is the **current** directory, i.e. the directory from which the `java` program was started. So, if you didn't execute Java from the right directory, or if your images are in a folder named `uploads`, it can't possibly work.

Comment: i have tried with `../../images` and `../images`. here is my folder structure `src
 -- mainpackage
  - Main.java
 -- configpackage
  - StaticFunction.java
images
 -- 1.png
 -- 2.png`

Comment: sorry. i dont know how to add line break in comments

Comment: Your folder structure is irrelevant. Read my comment, again. It insists on what the **current** directory is.

Comment: i understood what u are trying to say. but it's works when i run a project in eclipse. but it's not working after i convert it into jar. is there any solution for current folder structure (i have attached folder structure image).

Comment: i moved images into src folder. It's working now. thanks u all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your File is in the jar. So put a class named Locator in the same Directory. and use following code:

URL url = locator.getURL(name + ".gif");
 Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);

The class Locator is:

package schachfiguren;
 import java.net.*;
 public class Locator 
 {
     public URL getURL(String pfad)
     {
         URL url = this.getClass().getResource(pfad);
         return url;
     }
 }

pfad is the name of the File. For Example sbs.gif.

Comment: I get a NullPointerException only if the File is not in the same Directory as the Locator class.

Comment: my **images** folder is outside of my **src** folder. i moved **images** into **src** folder. It's working now. But when it is in outside, it works for normal project running but not for jar running.

Comment: i have tried with that. but got same result. then i move it into `src` and then tried your code. it works for both. i thought `images` inside `src` is not good practice. Anyway it's working now. thanks a lot.